# ¿Cómo eliminar el nodo sin eliminar su contenido con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un elemento en el DOM con la siguiente estructura:

```
<div>
<a class="clase-de-ejemplo" href=#><img/></a>
</div>
```

Como se puede observar, el enlace () contiene una imagen. Necesito borrar el nodo  sin eliminar su contenido para que el resultado sea:

```
<div>
<img/>
</div>
```

Hasta ahora lo que he conseguido es borrarlo con

```
$(".clase-de-ejemplo").parent().remove();
```

Pero esto me elimina el contenido entero. Antes de decantarme por la opción de guardar el contenido en una variable, borrarlo entero y volver a pintarlo sin el padre , me gustaría saber si existe algún procedimiento más sencillo.

Comment: No lo creo, ya que los nodos son una estructura en árbol, si eliminas una rama eliminas las hojas. Creo que la mejor opción es guardar el nodo hijo que quieres conservar y añadirlo al árbol en el lugar que quieres, en este caso dado que es el padre del `a`, será fácil ya que puedes usar directamente el `.parent()` para acceder a él desde el `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una alternativa es usar el método [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) para eliminar el nodo padre y reemplazarlo por el [contenido](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$(".clase-de-ejemplo").contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: :0 ¡Mucho más sencillo!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la manera más sencilla sería hacer un replace utilizando el html interno del elemento padre, así:

```
$(".clase-de-ejemplo").replaceWith($(".clase-de-ejemplo").html());
```

Igual considero que lo mejor seria guardar la **referencia** en una variable, lo propongo así por que lo especificas en tu pregunta. Con el fin de visualizar la funcionalidad hice el `div` color rojo, el `a` verde y la imagen es negra.

```js
function reemplazar() {
  $(".clase-de-ejemplo").replaceWith($(".clase-de-ejemplo").html());
  printHTML();
}

function printHTML() {
  console.log("Cobntenido del div padre: ", $(".padre").html());
}

printHTML();
```

```css
.padre {
  background-color: #F00;
}

a {
  background-color: #0F0;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="padre">
  <a class="clase-de-ejemplo" href=#> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlZK3.jpg?s=64&g=1" /></a>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="reemplazar()">Reemplazar</button>
```